Mature audience's topics?
Whenever I post an answer on foul language or sex-related questions, it gets downvotes.
foul language is a part of the language.
I would like to see a sub-forums like this http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/list.php?8  in Chinese language SE, so all 'dirty questions' can be directed there.
It is an example I am talking about
http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?8,143476

I support not censoring valid and legit content. As long as the question and the answers are legit (not spam, not abuse), there should be no external or self-imposed censorship. The academic curiosity of askers and competent spot-on answers of subject experts should not be stifled in any way. Proper tags and formatting of content might be enough to avoid triggering more sensible people.

To my knowledge, the closest thing Stack Exchange has to a sub-forum is tags: we can tag such questions accordingly (there's already swearing), then if someone wishes not to see foul language or sexual content, they can ignore the tags.  To use this, however, would require that we create and carefully maintain such tags.
Other possibilities are:

Users can include a "warning" in their post (e.g. write "not safe for work") or even use spoiler space (typeset >! hello world):

 hello world


As diamond mods, we can add "post notice" to questions and answers.  (This is probably something we should discuss more carefully beforehand.)

I understand there are various parental control software out there.


It's worth making sure content is not offensive, nor directed at anyone (as per the code of conduct).  However, these topics are unquestionably part of the Chinese language and people are going to be curious, so I don't think it's plausible nor reasonable to totally eliminate it.

Swearing in particular on Chinese.SE was brought up 5 years ago: Policy on swear words.  The main answers say:

As such, I believe that as long as the intention to asking the question is clearly specified and is perfectly valid, the question should be fine with swear words.
Thomas Hsieh


I was thinking we could use the EL&U policy:

No swearing in titles (titles can be shared in many ways and the local formatting might not properly show the entire title).
Swearing is allowed in body questions as long as the question is legit.

Alenanno

Searching for a particular swear word in other language sites: Japanese (6 Qs), German (7 Qs), French (10 Qs), Spanish (10 Qs), Latin (3 Qs).  So there's plenty of precedent for not worrying much about swearwords.

The other thing I want to point out is that, according to the Terms of Service, we are all 13 years of age or older.  In fact, Stack Exchange actually deletes accounts created by minors according to various laws:

Unfortunately, children under 13, or under 16 if located within the European Union, are not allowed to sign up for Stack Exchange accounts...
Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, and is there any way I can use it legally?

And... well... this is the Internet.  13-year olds are a few clicks away from far more extreme material.
